# How do I send and receive multiple selection values as ajax data?

Tags: ajax, flask

The value of multiple selectable select tags is sent as ajax data and will be null.

html code

```
<select id="dd" class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search" >
<optgroup label="filter1">
 <option>option1</option>
 <option>option2</option>
 </optgroup>
<optgroup label="filter2">
 <option>option1</option>
 <option>option2</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
<select  class="selectpicker"  name ='start_y'>
 <option value="2015">2015</option>
 <option value="2014">2014</option>
 <option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>
<select class="selectpicker"  name ='end_y'>
 <option value="2015">2015</option>
 <option value="2014">2014</option>
 <option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>

<button id ="go" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
```

script

select tag value ajax

```
$(function(){
  $('#go').click(function(){
  var city = $('#dd').val();
  var start_y = $('[name=start_y]').val();
  var end_y = $('[name=end_y]').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: '/signUpUser',
    data: {city:city,start_y:start_y,end_y:end_y},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  });

});
});
```

view

```
@app.route('/signUpUser', methods=['POST'])
   def siii():
   city =  request.form.get("city")
   start_y = request.form.get("start_y")
   end_y = request.form.get("end_y")
   return json.dumps({'city':city,'start_y':start_y,'end_y':end_y})
```

result

```
{"city":"null", "start_y":"2015", "end_y":"2016",}
```

Only select with multiple values ​​selected is null

???????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery ajax uses PHP style serialization, meaning an array parameter will be posted with `[]` appended to it. To avoid this set traditional to true in the request.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/signUpUser',
  data: {city:city,start_y:start_y,end_y:end_y},
  type: 'POST',
  traditional: true,
  success: function(response){
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```